# Flask SQLAlchemy - set expire_on_commit=False only for current session

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I set the option `expire_on_commit=False` only for the current session in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

I can set the option at the inizialization of the `SQLAlchemy` object with:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={"expire_on_commit": False})
```

but in this way all sessions created by Flask-SQLAlchemy will have the option set to False, instead i want to set it only for one session.

I tried `db.session.expire_on_commit = False` but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Have you tried the Session API? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html

Comment: I'm using the `Flask-SQLAlchemy` module that creates the session automatically at the request start, not vanilla `SQLAlchemy`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`expire_on_commit` is a parameter to the [`sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=expire_on_commit#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) class.

The preferred method of acquiring a `Session` instance, is through the [`sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=expire_on_commit#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker) class. Instances of `sessionmaker` are configured with settings that will be used to create `Session` instances. E.g.:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
>>> Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
>>> type(Session)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker'>
>>> session = Session()
>>> type(session)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>
```

So, calling a `sessionmaker` instance returns a `Session` instance.

With this configuration, each time we call our `sessionmaker` instance, we get a *new* `Session` instance back each time.

```
>>> session1 = Session()
>>> session2 = Session()
>>> session1 is session2
False
```

A [`scoped_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session) changes the above behaviour:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
>>> Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
>>> type(Session)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session'>
>>> session1 = Session()
>>> session2 = Session()
>>> session1 is session2
True
```

This is what Flask-SQLAlchemy uses 'under the hood' (and why @CodeLikeBeaker's comment directing you to the Session API was valid). It means that every time you call `db.session` when handling a `request` you are using the *same* underlying session. Here's the same example as above but using the `Flask-SQLAlchemy` extension.

```
>>> type(db.session)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session'>
>>> session1 = db.session()
>>> session2 = db.session()
>>> session1 is session2
True
```

Notice that `type(db.session)` in this example yields the exact same result as `type(Session)` in the previous example.

> all sessions created by Flask-SQLAlchemy will have the option set to
>   False, instead i want to set it only for one session.

Given the fact that Flask-SQLAlchemy only creates one session per request, I take this to mean that you sometimes want a session to `expire_on_commit` and sometimes not, when handling a request.

One way that you can achieve that is by using a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) to temporarily turn `expire_on_commit` off:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def no_expire():
    s = db.session()
    s.expire_on_commit = False
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        s.expire_on_commit = True
```

And here is my test model:

```
class Person(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(16))
```

Configure logging to see what `SQLAlchemy` is doing:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Create some test data:

```
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
names = ('Jane', 'Tarzan')
db.session.add_all([Person(name=n) for n in names])
db.session.commit()
```

This is the function I've used for testing:

```
def test_func():
    # query the db
    people = Person.query.all()
    # commit the session
    db.session.commit()
    # iterate through people accessing name to see if sql is emitted
    for person in people:
        print(f'Person is {person.name}')
    db.session.rollback()
```

The I run the test function once without the context manager:

```
test_func()
```

Here is the stdout:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT person.id AS person_id, person.name AS person_name
FROM person
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT person.id AS person_id, person.name AS person_name
FROM person
WHERE person.id = %(param_1)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'param_1': 1}
*****Person is Jane*****
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT person.id AS person_id, person.name AS person_name
FROM person
WHERE person.id = %(param_1)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'param_1': 2}
*****Person is Tarzan*****
```

It can be seen that after the commit, sql is reissued to refresh the object attributes.

And once using the context manager:

```
db.session.rollback()
with no_expire():
    test_func()
```

And here is stdout with the context manager:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:ROLLBACK
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT person.id AS person_id, person.name AS person_name
FROM person
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
*****Person is Jane*****
*****Person is Tarzan*****
```