# How to prevent a SQLAlchemy commit from affecting undeferred columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy [deferred loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_columns.html#deferred-column-loading) on a text column, and if I query for a single entity and `undefer` its normally deferred column, the column I indicated should be undeferred is present:

```py
video = (
    session.query(Video)
    .options(undefer(Video.transcript))
    .filter_by(id=video_id)
    .one_or_none()
)

# When serializing `video` here, `transcript` is present as expected
```

However, if I call `commit()` on the SQLAlchemy session after the initial query, the deferred column is no longer present:

```py
video = (
    session.query(Video)
    .options(undefer(Video.transcript))
    .filter_by(id=video_id)
    .one_or_none()
)

session.commit()

# When serializing `video` after a commit, `transcript` is NOT present
```

I encountered this when doing other work between the initial lookup query and the `commit()` but reduced it to this simple example and still observed the behavior.

How can I prevent a `commit()` from wiping out the column(s) I wish to remain undeferred?

Comment: Committing will expire all attribute data by default.  You can prevent this by setting [expire_on_commit](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.params.expire_on_commit) to `True` on your session.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Add that as an answer, and I'll mark is as accepted. Thanks!  Knowing this now, I found this answer, which helps my specific use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446322/flask-sqlalchemy-set-expire-on-commit-false-only-for-current-session